# How do I disconnect all devices connected to a Hotmail/Outlook.com account?

Tags: outlook.com

My father had his Hotmail account hacked and someone sent messages. The hacker has access to his Hotmail inbox.

I've changed his password, but when I changed it, the web sessions were not killed, so the hacker still connected.